# Is there alternative available to jqx render capability - $gridContainer.jqxGrid('render')

Tags: jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

We are using jqxGrid library from [jqwidgets](https://www.jqwidgets.com/). In this I am using `jqxDropDownList` for displaying list created from json data and upon selecting a value from dropdown filtering should happen.

We had some UI issues hence we had to remove below line, now I would like to know is there alternative available for below code :

code :

```
$gridContainer.jqxGrid('render')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update two-way data then you should used `observableArray()`

here check the demo code [jqx observable array](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxobservablearray/javascript-observable-array.htm?search=obse)

```
var observableArray = new $.jqx.observableArray(
[{name: "Andrew Smith"},
 {name: "Gordon Brown"}], 
function(changes)
{
    // handle changes here.
});
```